# Attaching debugger to w3wp results in system.identityModel not being found

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, iis

We develop a web application (SPA, REST web API). I can run the application on my local IIS (not IIS Express) without any issues.
But as soon as I attach the Visual Studio 2017 debugger (as administrator) to the process w3wp.exe and then try to call any web API endpoint from the web client, I get the error

```
ID7027: Could not load the identity configuration because no configuration section was found.
```

When I detach from the process the error remains until I close Visual Studio.

Any ideas or suggestions on how to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found the issue: when attaching the debugger, Visual Studio started IIS Express which was then called instead of my local IIS. For IIS Express, there was no inheritance of the web.config files.

I had to change project settings to NOT use IIS Express.